# git: get all files from remote repository

Tags: git

I'll be honest, my background is SVN, git completely confuses me, and git's documentation doesn't make any sense to me.

I know from some communications from coworkers that there are additional directories and files that are in the remote repository from stuff they've been working on. I don't see them locally. I would like my local working space to reflect all those changes. I don't know the names of all the files -- there might be hundreds.

Something like clone, but doesn't complain about a local copy being present. I've tried out all kinds of commands and got nowhere, either "fatal error" or "already up-to-date".

So far, I've managed to overwrite and lose some existing work. Don't know how I did it -- I thought version control should never let this happen!

Comment: In Git, there is no classical "working copy" like in SVN. When you clone a Git repository, you create a full-blown copy, including the entire revision history. I would suggest reading some tutorials on the topic -- for example, the [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/de) is excellent; furthermore, there is a great [interactive tutorial at Github](http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `git`, you always have a clone of a remote depot.

The rough equivalent of `svn update` is `git fetch` which fetch all new commits from the remote depot followed by a `git merge remote/master` (or you can use the `git pull` command that does those two steps). It is generally a good idea to commit locally all your changes before doing `git merge` or `git pull` (`git fetch` is safe) as this will attempt to merge your changes with the remote branch, and can result in conflicts.

The rough equivalent of `svn commit` is `git push` that will send your changes to the remote depot and will update the reference to the branch head there. You should always do a merge before doing a push otherwise you may delete your coworker changes by accident. Your team may have another workflow though (sending patch to a single person responsible for integration).

If you're coming from `svn`, the easiest way to understand `git` is to think that you are always working on a branch and that sharing with the rest of the team is done by merging the reference branch in yours or yours in the reference branch.

Otherwise, I would really recommend reading [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/) or at least the [Git SVN crash course](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnCrashCourse).

Comment: Are you in the correct branch? Have you merged the correct branch? You can try `git checkout -b ${new-branch-name} remote/${name-of-remote-branch}` and see if you get all the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What I did was discard my local and clone a new one. It is complete. Somehow I must have irreversibly messed up my local.